# gecko clear cache history & cookies

Tags: c#, cookies, gecko

Help! I use **GeckoFx-Windows-10.0-0.6** for browser and **xulrunner-10.0.en-US.win32**. ( Visual Studio 2010 c# ) everything works well. But i need to clear all history as at Firefox : 
 Tools >> Options >> Privacy

I find how clear cookie over `Gecko.CookieManager.RemoveAll();`

How clear cache , temp files and history ?!

And when i initialize `Gecko.Xpcom` i can not clean the folder `"Gecko.Xpcom.ProfileDirectory"` (where cache and cookie)  for obvious reasons.
`Gecko.Xpcom.Shutdown()` does not help

---

I found a way to clean the cookies via javascript :

`var cookieManager = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/cookiemanager;1"].getService(Components.interfa‌​ces.nsICookieManager); 
cookieManager.removeAll();`

How right call this JS in C#?

Answer (score 6):

To clear cookies you will need to query interface like this:

```
    if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete cookies?", "About to delete all cookies", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        nsICookieManager CookieMan;
        CookieMan = Xpcom.GetService<nsICookieManager>("@mozilla.org/cookiemanager;1");
        CookieMan = Xpcom.QueryInterface<nsICookieManager>(CookieMan);
        CookieMan.RemoveAll();
    }
```

An access to cache is denied during runtime brobably cause of security or such.
Meaning you will need to find a way to delete these folders after you program closes etc.
create another app for handling it.

Answer (score 2):

For what its worth and since I looked a while for this, on GeckoFX 29 at least history follows the same pattern:

```
nsIBrowserHistory historyMan = Xpcom.GetService<nsIBrowserHistory>(Gecko.Contracts.NavHistoryService);
historyMan = Xpcom.QueryInterface<nsIBrowserHistory>(historyMan);
historyMan.RemoveAllPages();
```

For Cache without being sure is the correct way:

```
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/imgICache
Gecko.Cache.ImageCache.ClearCache(true);
Gecko.Cache.ImageCache.ClearCache(false);
// Defaults to all devices(0) - https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-9.0/issue/7/idl-translation-bug-for-enums
Gecko.Cache.CacheService.Clear(new CacheStoragePolicy());
```

Comment: Error `System.NotImplementedException: 'The method or operation is not implemented.'`  at `Gecko.Cache.CacheService.Clear(new CacheStoragePolicy());`

Comment: Are you sure you are using GeckoFX 29 ? This was answered so long ago that's hard to provide any valuable input currently.