# How to delete the browser history, cookies etc from firefox with C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, internet-explorer, firefox

Currently I have an application that deletes the cookies, browser history etc for IE(Internet Explorer)
And I want to be able to have the same functions but for Firefox and eventually Chrome.

Not sure how that would take place since I've never deleted history etc from Firefox before.

This is the code for IE

```
private void quickCleanButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (internetExplorerCheckbox.IsChecked == true)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 4351");
            }
            else
            {

            }
```

^That cleans everything in IE

```
    if(tempIEcheckBox.IsChecked == true)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 8");
    }
    else
    {

    }
```

^And this clears the temp files.

How do I access the same features but fore Firefox or is it even possible
?

Comment: Did you see this question? Looks like you might be able to do something like that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513063/gecko-clear-cache-history-cookies I don't have a full answer but Mozilla SDK seems like the way to go.